# Update mysql table using POST method

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with some textbox that loads the data from the database. I have created also a button where I can update the data but currently it's not working and I don't have any clue why.

Here's my query:

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

if (isset($_POST['btnUpdate'])){

    $query = "UPDATE users SET fname = '".$_POST['fname']."', lname = '".$_POST['lname']."' WHERE user_id = '".$_POST['id']."'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if ($result) {
        die("<strong>Updated</strong>");
    } else {
        die("<strong>Error ".mysql_error()."</strong>");
    }
}
?>
```

Here's my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>"/>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">First name:</label>
   <div class="col-lg-8">
   <input class="form-control" name="fname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['fname'];?>">
   </div>

  <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Last name:</label>
  <div class="col-lg-8">
  <input class="form-control" name="lname" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['lname'];?>">
  </div>

 <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
 <div class="col-md-8" >
 <input type="button" name="btnUpdate" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes">
 <span></span>
 <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I've tried everything but it won't update my database. It doesn't have any error whatsoever when I checked it on the browser. I'm running out of ideas. Anyone know what part of my code is wrong? I'm still a beginner to php and I cannot seem to understand what's wrong here. Any ideas how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: the attribute for `$_POST['id']` is where exactly? there is a simple way to do this btw

Comment: *"Any ideas how to solve this problem"* - A: hidden input. `<input class="form-control" name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">`. Ok people, nothing else to see here ;-)

Comment: Also be aware that somebody could cause heavy damage to your database and you're using an outdated MySQL API. Consider using [parameterization](http://bobby-tables.com/php)

Comment: make btnUpdate type as submit... no action defined....
How you are sure its going to that file....?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have edited the form now. I forgot to copy the line. Sorry

Comment: use what @Naincy said; `<input type="button"` => `<input type="submit"` and if that doesn't work, then check for errors via php's error reporting and on the query.

Comment: @Naincy You're a life saver. It works now. Thanks mate appreciated.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is working now. Thanks mate :)

Comment: @JakeMeister great!

Comment: You're welcome Jake. If what @Naincy said solved it, then you should invite them to post it as an answer. However, and if they do; to include a good explanation and not just "drop code" in it. There is a "reason" ;-)

Comment: as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button under **"type"**.

Comment: btw @JakeMeister I hope you're not live or going live with this are you? If so, it's an old and deprecated api and open to a serious sql injection. We wouldn't want your site to get hacked.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Noted on that. I will asked them next time. I have plans already on learning the Mysqli or PDO but until now I'm still working on my thesis and I don't have time to study those apis. Thanks for the information. I will keep that link.

Comment: You're welcome Jake. I waited for @Naincy to post an answer but they didn't. In not doing so, I thought I would post a community wiki answer and not make any rep off this; it wouldn't be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting as a community wiki; I feel no rep should come of it.

`<input type="button">` does not by default propagate POST. Therefore you either need to use a "submit" type:

Either `<input type="submit">` or `<button type="submit">`.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button

**type**
    The type of the button. Possible values are:

- submit: The button submits the form data to the server. This is the default if the attribute is not specified, or if the attribute is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
- reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
- button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are triggered when the events occur.

You're also open to a serious SQL injection if your site is live or intended to go live.

You should start looking into switching over to either the `mysqli_` or PDO api and with a prepared statement.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection